# How to remove object from array if property in object do not exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have the following collection of data

```
[{
 id: '1',
 date: '2017-01-01',
 value: 2
 },
 {
 id: '2',
 date: '2017-01-02',
 value: 3
 },
 {
 id: '3',
 value: 3
 },
 id: '4',
 date: '2017-01-02',
 value: 3
 }]
```

I want to delete any object that does not have the 'date' property. In the example above, the object with the id 3 should be deleted.

The finished object should look like this

```
[{
 id: '1',
 date: '2017-01-01',
 value: 2
 },
 {
 id: '2',
 date: '2017-01-02',
 value: 3
 },
 id: '4',
 date: '2017-01-02',
 value: 3
 }]
```

I tried to find and delete a undefined value with lodash. It does not work. The object looks exactly as it is entering.

```
  _.each(obj, (val) => {
    _.remove(val, value => value['XXX-BUDAT'] === undefined);
   });
```

How can I use lodash for this purpose?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let input = [
   { id: '1', date: '2017-01-01', value: 2},
   { id: '2', date: '2017-01-02', value: 3},
   { id: '3', value: 3 },
   { id: '4', date: '2017-01-02', value: 3 }
]
 
 let output = input.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).includes("date"));
 
 console.log(output);
```

Comment: ah ok. Instead of removing you create and object with keys that includes date. Nice thank you mickl

Comment: @Ckappo If this was useful to you, please [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) this question for future readers and consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if you think it is the best one for your question.

Comment: @mickl It might make more sense to use `Object.hasOwnProperty`, wouldnt it? That way you dont have to generate + iterate the object key collection.

Answer (score 4):

You can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array based on that property like this:

```js
const initial = [{
    id: '1',
    date: '2017-01-01',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    date: '2017-01-02',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    value: 3
  }, { // this left curly brace was missing!, check that out
    id: '4',
    date: '2017-01-02',
    value: 3
  }
];

const finalR = initial.filter((obj) => obj.hasOwnProperty('date') && !!obj.date);

console.log(finalR);
```

Comment: Note that this may cause problems as it looks up the prototype chain too.

Comment: I don't know why my previous comment was deleted.... anyway. The answer is updated after the comment of _ibrahim mahrir_

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array#filter` and `Object#hasOwnProperty` to do so:

```
var newArray = oldArray.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty("date");
});
```

Which can be shortened out using an arrow function:

```
var newArray = oldArray.filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty("date"));
```

Lodash solution:

```
var newArray = _.filter(oldArray, obj => _.has(obj, "date"));
```

**Example:**

```js
var oldArray = [{id: '1', date: '2017-01-01', value: 2 }, { id: '2', date: '2017-01-02', value: 3 }, { id: '3', value: 3 }, {id: '4', date: '2017-01-02', value: 3}];

var newArray = oldArray.filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty("date"));

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). In addition, you can use ES6 object assignment destructiring to make it concise:

```
var data=[{id:'1',date:'2017-01-01',value:2},{id:'2',date:'2017-01-02',value:3},{id:'3',value:3},{id:'4',date:'2017-01-02',value:3}];

var result = data.filter(({date}) => date);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your array of object is not valid, fix it by wrapping the last object element with preceding curly brace `{`. See [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) that'll check your current object item has the `date` key or not? if it has then it'll return that object other wise that item will not return.

```js
var array_of_object = [{
    id: '1',
    date: '2017-01-01',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    date: '2017-01-02',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    value: 3
  },
  { //missing brace here
    id: '4',
    date: '2017-01-02',
    value: 3
  }
];


function filterByValue(item) {
  return item.hasOwnProperty('date');
}
var arrByID = array_of_object.filter(filterByValue);
console.log(arrByID);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a native javascript solution:

```js
var arr = [
  {id: '1', date: '2017-01-01', value: 2},
  {id: '2', date: '2017-01-02', value: 3},
  {id: '3', value: 3},
  {id: '4', date: '2017-01-02', value: 3}
]

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(!arr[i].hasOwnProperty("date")) {
    arr.splice(i,1);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Note that this may cause problems as it looks up the prototype chain too. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367551/how-to-remove-object-from-array-if-property-in-object-do-not-exist/51367602?noredirect=1#comment89707624_51367602); I omitted this as well in my first attempt to answer the question :) A solution could be to use the `hasOwnProperty` func.