# Javascript: How do I remove an object with a specific key in my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am having difficulty finding how to remove an object from an array using its key - I can only find advice on a key value. For example:

```
var users = [
  { 1: [{age: 36, active: true}] },
  { 2: [{age: 40, active: false}] },
  { 3: [{age: 37, active: true}]}
];
```

I would like to remove the object with key = 2 to result in this:

```
var users = [
  { 1: [{age: 36, active: true}] },
  { 3: [{age: 37, active: true}]}
];
```

My keys in my data are unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to remove object from array if property in object do not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367551/how-to-remove-object-from-array-if-property-in-object-do-not-exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator to check if the key exists on the object:

```js
const users = [{"1":[{"age":36,"active":true}]},{"2":[{"age":40,"active":false}]},{"3":[{"age":37,"active":true}]}]

const result = users.filter(o => !('2' in o))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

and [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property **names**, iterated in the same order that a normal loop would.

```js
var users = [
  { 1: [{age: 36, active: true}] },
  { 2: [{age: 40, active: false}] },
  { 3: [{age: 37, active: true}]}
];
users = users.filter(item => Object.keys(item)[0] != 2);
console.log(users);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove an object from the original array without creating a new array, use `Array.findIndex` and remove the element by the index.

```js
var users = [
  { 1: [{age: 36, active: true}] },
  { 2: [{age: 40, active: false}] },
  { 3: [{age: 37, active: true}]}
];


let removableIndex = users.findIndex(ele => ele[2])

users.splice(removableIndex, 1)

console.log(users)
```

Comment: This is the better solution

Comment: @mplungjan why is this better than the accepted answer?  Just curious.

Comment: Because it loops until the index is found and then stops immediately